# Formatting harddrive for data storage

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ssd, filesystems

I have an SSD and a HDD drive stored on my computer. The SSD is for running programs and the OS and the HDD is for storing media, data, and other things that don't require fast read and write speeds.  The plan was to use Linux as my OS and run windows on a virtual machine (on a partition within the SSD).

I want to easily be able to mount the secondary hard drive (the HDD) and access it regardless of which OS am I am.

*What filesystem should I use/what would be the best way to implement such a plan?*

Originally,I was going to use gparted, format the hard drive to NTSF, and then get an NTSF driver for linux so it can read the disk. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts are fine. 
Currently, the Microsoft "NTFS" file system can be easily read from / written to from a variety of operating systems (Windows, Linux, Mac OS).

Recent Linux distributions (Fedora, Ubuntu) already include the ntfs-3g drivers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G) in order to access those partitions.

If not, you may install them by the system package installer (e.g. yum install ntfs-3g ...)

I suggest using NTFS, it works very well for me.

Comment: I ended up going with the ntfs. I'll keep the superuser topic updated on how it goes.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 has native ntfs support. Nice call.